# Already available Test cases for Android

Tags: android, junit, open-source, servicetestcase, testcasesource

Is there any open source test cases codes available for android junit. Like, test cases for android media player, content providers etc? I have searched through Google and cannot find related links. I'm testing using my test cases now but I want to know whether test cases are already available. Planning to reuse those as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the platform's unit tests or the CTS (Compatibility Test Suite), download android source code from [AOSP](http://source.android.com/source/index.html), they are included. Unless you are trying to modify the platform though, those won't be to useful. No one can really create reusable tests for an app you are writing.